Converting time
I am creating a timecard in Excel.
In-out-in-out-in-out-total
Let's say my total is 8:38
Eight hours and 38 minutes.
I have written the below IF statement to convert my minutes, but I cant figure out how to ONLY read the minutes.
=IF(I5<0.08,"0",
IF(OR(I5<0.23),".25",
IF(OR(I5<0.38),".50",
IF(OR(I5<0.53),".75",
IF(OR(I5<0.6),"

My goal is to convert the 38 minutes into .75
Everything I am trying is converting hours and minutes into minutes.

Your description is incomprehensible. 45 Minutes equal 0,75 hours but you do not explain according to which rules 38 minutes should be transformed into .75.

@r2d3 37.5 minutes is the mid point between 30(.5) and 45(.75).  The op is only dealing with full minutes and as such 37 would go to .5 and the next minute crosses the mid point and would round to .75

Seems easier to just enter 7.25, 7.50, and 7.75 to handle (15, 30, and 45 minutes). Many time systems only accept quarter hours.

Total time in decimal hours, rounded to the nearest quarter hour, would be =INT(A1*24)+MROUND(MOD(A1*24,1),0.25)

Use MROUND:
=MROUND(MOD(I5*24,1),0.25)

The MOD strips the hours out and then rounds the minutes to the nearest quarter.

